# Hampton Bay Ceiling Fan with a remote with 3 speeds fan and 3 lights option and 2 wall switches

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, remote-control

Ceiling wirings are Black, Red, White and Ground
There are 2 wall switches and one for the light on/off and the other is for fan on/off

Here is what I have wired and the wall switches for light and fan work but the remote only controls light options and it won't control fan speed.

Ceiling ground to bracket ground

White ceiling  to White Receiver Input and White Fan

Black ceiling to Black fan

Blue Receiver Output to Blue in fan

Red Ceiling to Black Receiver Input

Cap off Black and White from Receiver Output

What am I missing to make the remote works for the fan speeds?

Thanks

Comment: Are you OK with getting a different remote control setup for your fan?

Answer (score 1):

Your remote doesn't control the fan speeds because you went from the ceiling black to the fan, bypassing the remote.
To use the remote to control the light and fan, you need the white and one of the ceiling red or black to go to the receiver input. the receiver will now be switched from one of the wall switched. The blue receiver output goes to the fan light blue. The black receiver output goes to the fan motor black. The other whites get wired to the receiver white output. Your one wall switch will need to be on to have the remote work correctly, you can't have the switches and remote work independently... you have to choose how you want to operate the fan and lights.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I will try your advise.